# screen pixels are unstable after upgrade ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, screen

after upgrading Ubuntu and after reboot, my laptop screen pixels start to be unstable but if i am connected to a second screen the second screen pixels are fine it's only happen on my laptop,
i tried to install Fedora and it's was good also after running upgrade it start again, somebody have any suggestion how to fix it?

graphic card info:

```
  *-display                 
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:35 memory:d0000000-d0ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:b2000000-b207ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:36 memory:d1000000-d13fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: Include info on your graphics card (`sudo lshw -class display`) and your Ubuntu and kernel version `uname -a`

Comment: hey @vanadium, i edit the message and i moving back to fedora without upgrading, because Ubuntu killed my eyes, but i was in Ubuntu 20.04 lts.

Answer (score -3):

Just downgrade ubuntu again and after few months upgrade it again because many time upgrade broke things and it takes time to fix them.